# How to auto scroll images in android

Tags: android, autoscroll

I want to display bunch of images at the starting of my app and changing images one after another sequentially with slow auto horizantal scrolling can any one tell me how to do this android I searched in Google but I didn't get the answer can any one tell me how to do this please thanks in big advance

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: try this tutorial http://moorandroid.blogspot.in/p/image-slide-show.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) for screen slides

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ViewPager for Image slider in android to scroll images:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```